# CORS issue with T3 app when accessing external API

Tags: reactjs, api, cors, trpc.io, t3

I am trying to send a barcode taken with a camera and send it to an external API to retrieve product information, and I am being blocked by CORS.

There error I am receiving is:

Access to fetch at 'https://brocade.io/api/items/6076451728682' from origin 'https://quarter-master2.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I am also receiving the same error on the dev server.  I used create-t3-app to scaffold this app and per the docs on enabling cors (https://create.t3.gg/en/usage/trpc#enabling-cors), I have the following in my `[trpc].ts` file:

```
import { createNextApiHandler } from "@trpc/server/adapters/next";
import { type NextApiRequest, type NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { env } from "~/env.mjs";

import { appRouter } from "~/server/api/root";
import { createTRPCContext } from "~/server/api/trpc";
import cors from "nextjs-cors";

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  // Enable cors
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
  await cors(req, res);

  // Create and call the tRPC handler
  return createNextApiHandler({
    router: appRouter,
    createContext: createTRPCContext,
    onError:
      env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? ({ path, error }) => {
            console.error(
              `❌ tRPC failed on ${path ?? "<no-path>"}: ${error.message}`
            );
          }
        : undefined,
  })(req, res);
};

export default handler;
```

Here is the fetch request made from the frontend, which is called from a useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function getUPCInfo() {
      if (barcode !== null) {
        console.log(barcode);
        const res = await fetch(
          
          `https://brocade.io/api/items/${barcode}`,
          { mode: "cors" }
        );

        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);
        alert(res.json());
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
    getUPCInfo();
  }, [barcode]);
```

It has been a while since I've dealt with external API calls in react so I could be missing something silly but I can't find what it is.

Any help understand and fixing this is greatly appreciated.